# Is there a way to get Apache to serve files with the question mark in their name?

Tags: apache

I scraped a bunch of pages using wget -m -k -E. The resulting files have names in the form foo.php?bar.html. Apache guesses everything after the ? is a query string, is there a way to tell it to ignore the ? as the query string delimiter (and see foo.php?bar.html as the requested file and not foo.php)?

To save you a trip to wget manpage:
-m : mirror recursively
-E : foo.php?bar becomes foo.php?bar.html
-k : convert links in pages (foo.php?bar now links to foo.php?bar.html inside of all the pages so they display properly)

Comment: To what end? Do really have a file called foo.php?bar.html on your filesystem? Or is an issue with logs? Something else?

Comment: Yes, there was a series of files on the filesystem with foo.php?bar.html names.  They were the result of wget's -E flag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would escaping the ? as %3F do the trick?

Answer (score 3):

Apache v1 used to handle them, however v2 does not.

I did it using mod_rewrite. Nathans' suggestion in a form of code:

```
RewriteEngine On 

# Convert ? -> %3F in queries and add .html to the end of the filename
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1\%3F%{QUERY_STRING}.html [L,NE]

# An addition for *.php files without question mark in its name, adding html to the end of the filename
RewriteRule ^(.*?)\.php$ $1.php.html
```